# Recursive cURL not returning results

Tags: php, curl

I am performing a cURL on an ssl page *(Page1.php)* that in turn performs a cURL on an SSL page *(Page2.php)*.  Both pages are on my site and within the same directory and both pages return XML.  Through logging I see that *Page2.php* is being hit and is outputting valid XML. I can also hit *page2.php* in a browser and it returns valid XML.  However, page1.php is timing and out never returning the XML.

Here is the relevant code from Page1.php:

```
$url = "https://mysite.com/page2.php"
$c = curl_init($url);

if ($c)
{
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
 }
```

`$result` never has anything in it.

*Page2* has similar options set but its $result var does have a the expected data in it.

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to PHP so I'm hoping that I'm overlooking something really simple here.

BTW, we are using a `WAMP` setup with `Windows Server 2008`.

Comment: what's your `curl_getinfo` output after calling `curl_exec` ?

Comment: Could you show some *page2*'s code ?

Comment: curl_getinfo from page 1:  [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 83
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 3.01
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.093
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] =>